# OOZIE fails due to "JA009: No such file or directory"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to run jobs in Hadoop with oozie, hadoop and oozie versions are:

```
[root@10-0-87-4 /]# hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.8.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r 042da8b868a212c843bcbf3594519dd26e816e79
Compiled by jenkins on 2016-07-12T23:02Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 2b6c319ecc19f118d6e1c823175717b5
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.8.0.jar

[root@10-0-87-4 /]# oozie version
Oozie client build version: 3.3.2.1.3.2.0-111
```

The oozie is not native from CDH repo, I've installed it by:

```
$ wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/1.x/updates/1.3.2.0/hdp.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/hdp.repo
$ yum install -y oozie extjs-2.2-1 --disablerepo cloudera-cdh5
```

This is the way I need it to work, **please don't suggest to install native oozie from CDH5 as I need this specific oozie**.

The problem starts when I want to run some job I'm getting this error:

```
/var/log/oozie/oozie.log:2016-10-10 12:22:03,245  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - SERVER[] USER[u_1813] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[execute-wf] JOB[0000000-161010120015197-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-161010120015197-oozie-oozi-W@run-luigi] Error starting action [run-luigi]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: No such file or directory]
/var/log/oozie/oozie.log:2016-10-10 12:22:04,275  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - SERVER[] USER[u_1813] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[execute-wf] JOB[0000000-161010120015197-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-161010120015197-oozie-oozi-W@run-luigi] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

I checked the workflow and all mentioned files are located in HDFS,

```
  <file>python.sh#python.sh</file>
  <file>oozie-luigi-pig-workflow.py#oozie-luigi-pig-workflow.py</file>
  <file>/user/oozie/share/private_key#private_key</file>
  <file>hdfs://hdfs.<some-link>:8020/user/u_1813/oozie/workflows/pig-execute/lib/file-s3distcp.jar#file-s3distcp.jar</file>
  <file>hdfs://hdfs.<some-link>:8020/user/u_1813/oozie/workflows/pig-execute/lib/file_udfs.rb#file_udfs.rb</file>
```

Namenode\Datanode\Tasktracker\Jobtracker\PIG- Process are running without any problem, the only problem is with Oozie.

Extra logs from `/var/log/oozie/oozie.log`

```
2016-10-17 18:05:45,148  WARN UserGroupInformation:1696 - SERVER[] PriviledgedActionException as:u_1813 (auth:PROXY) via oozie (auth:SIMPLE) cause:ENOENT: No such file or directory
2016-10-17 18:05:45,148  WARN UserGroupInformation:1696 - SERVER[] PriviledgedActionException as:u_1813 (auth:PROXY) via oozie (auth:SIMPLE) cause:ENOENT: No such file or directory
2016-10-17 18:05:45,148  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - SERVER[] USER[u_1813] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[execute-wf] JOB[0000000-161017180107504-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-161017180107504-oozie-oozi-W@prepare-script] Error starting action [prepare-script]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: No such file or directory]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:418)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:396)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:762)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:913)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:211)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:277)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ENOENT: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:573)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:564)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:747)
    ... 8 more
```

BTW, Oozie is working with postgresql-server and it's working propertly I can access to Oozie UI and can see the Jobs and ext.. The problem starts when I'm trying to run any kind of Jobs.

Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks,
EddieM

Comment: are you able to run any workflow or you are seeing the error with coordinators?

Comment: Not able to run any kind of workflow. :(

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: other than above warn messages are you seeing any details error message?

Comment: I edited my question and added extra logs.

Comment: I think this issue is related to the permissions on HDFS can you try adding the user used for starting the oozie service to hadoop group?

Comment: @EddieM did u solve that issue?

Comment: @subzero Unfortunately no :(